# How to get rid of a logo in wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am using a theme that I really like but their "designed by" logo is an Obnoxious place. Right in the middle of the page on the left hand side... how can I get rid of this and move it to the footer?

http://detailhavasu.com/

Comment: Illegal dude, read the terms. When in doubt; fork out! ;)

Answer (score 7):

That would be illegal if you haven't bought it, see the `style.css` file:

> Notice: This theme is free for personal use. For commercial use or removing [Wordspop](http://wordspop.com/) link, please [buy this theme](https://www.e-junkie.com/ecom/gb.php?i=637393&c=single&cl=108569).